# Ask confirmation BEFORE Redirect from page

Tags: javascript, jquery, sammy.js

I have application.
Client side is - knockout.

so I have page with form, and i want to ask user confirametion before he will try go to another page (in case if he changed something (this pard is ready))

So routing on all website  - its Sammy.js.

I tried :
Sammy JS - before

```
function ViewModel()
{
  Sammy.before(/.*/, function () {

        if (window.confirm('Really go to another page?')){

        }
        else{
            //DO NOTHING AND STAY IN THE SAME PAGE
            //OR SOMETHING ELSE THAT YOU WANT

            return false;
        }

     });
}
```

its work , but its still working for all website - and its bad.
I'm not found way to disable it, so maybe I can do it without sammy???

Thank you guys!

Update: This website is SPA

Comment: You can do it with simple JS, with window.onbeforeunload = function() { if(something_is_changed) { return 'Really go to another page?'; } }

Comment: You could check for the form_id before asking for confirmation

Comment: Yep @BalázsVarga is right, use the onbeforeunload event, see here for reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

Comment: No, guys - I forget to say - my website is SPA. So inbeforeunload - work only with F5/ctrl+r, but if i try to another tab - he don's it like reload, becouse SPA

Comment: David, is someone know what Sammy.js is, he knows it's an SPA and doesn't give this kind of answer. It's not your fault, but theirs fault for answering without paying too much attention.

Comment: I answered a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23955762/394418

Comment: There is a javascript event for leaving the tab too, called window.onblur, or in older IE versions document.onfocusout .

Answer (score 0):

You can use `before`, but you must specify options to show the confirmation dialog only when necessary. See the [docs](http://sammyjs.org/docs/api/0.7.4/all#Sammy.Application-before). You're specifying to run it for all the routes, you must specify in which routes you want it executed. Before option only gives you information on the next route. If it depends on the current route, you can get it examining the  current url:

```
function extractSammyUrlFrom (context)
{
  // get the hash fragment (curernt route)
  "#" + context.path.split("#")[1] ;
}
```

If it depends on any other thing in your page, just check it before showing the dialog.

Comment: I know. But I need to ALL ROUTES! because I want ask him if user want LEAVE CURRENT Page - and it not interesting to which page he go - because it I need to ALL pages

Comment: Then, what is the answer? You have it working for all the wbesite, don't you?