# Confirm before redirecting to another page/route

Tags: javascript, sammy.js

I have been trying to ask user before leaving the page a confirmation in knockout.js using `before` callback of sammy.js in my case for a specific URL here is the code what i wrote.

```
 router.sammy = Sammy(function () {

            this.before('#view/?:viewThingObj?/edit', function() {
                if(!window.confirm('Are you sure you want to leave this page?')) {
                    return false;
                }
            });

            this.before(/.*/, function () {
                }
});
```

but it doesn't seems to be working is there something wrong? is this because of the route i added for all i.e. `/.*/`

Answer (score 1):

My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23955762/394418) should do what you're trying to do. My group had to abandon before because it still changed the URL prior to attempting to run the route.